# Adding two separate charts into single chart using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have two separate charts in GEE with values but its giving error when I try to combine both into single one. It's saying no properties to chart. The problem I'm facing is here

```
var elevation = DEMIMAGE.reduceRegions(points, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
var elevation2 = DEMIMAGE2.reduceRegions(points, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
var seriesChart = [elevation, elevation2];
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(seriesChart));
```

The code link is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/84ab7902eb1db9aee4590a689ed50ca4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` in order to combine your two feature collections. Also, because of GEE console has 5000 limit, when merging, this can exceed the limit. I narrow your range to 500 in each collection, and the result seems fine.

```
// add variables
var numbPoints = 500; // spacing in lat/lon between the sample points

var point1 = ee.List(CrossSection1.coordinates().get(0));
var point2 = ee.List(CrossSection1.coordinates().get(1));
var XmapList = ee.List.sequence(point1.get(0), point2.get(0), null, numbPoints);
var YmapList = ee.List.sequence(point1.get(1), point2.get(1), null, numbPoints);


// Construct a feature collection with points equally spaced
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(XmapList.map(function(Xcoord){
  var Ycoord = YmapList.get(XmapList.indexOf(Xcoord));
  return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([Xcoord, Ycoord]));
}));

// Calculate the elevation at every location
var DEMIMAGE = image; 
var DEMIMAGE2 = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4'); // load an image with elevation

// Map.addLayer(image, {min:0,max:500})
var elevation = DEMIMAGE.reduceRegions(points, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
var elevation2 = DEMIMAGE2.reduceRegions(points, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
print('elevation', elevation)
// print(seriesChart)

print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(elevation,"system:index", "first"));
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(elevation2));

var seriesChart = elevation.merge(elevation2); print(seriesChart)
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(seriesChart, "system:index", "first"));
```